# Is there a reason most of author assumed i.i.d in copula models.

Tags: copula

I read many of copula articles. I almost found that the authors assumed the i.i.d observations in copula models. I just wonder if there is a reason for this assumption? I searched this site and found one question with an answer but the answer is not what I meant by this question.

[Here is the link to the question:](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52086/why-do-copulas-need-the-i-i-d-assumption-for-marginal-distribution)

The question is so old. I do not know how to activate it.

Comment: How would you approach fitting a distribution to the data if the data values were interdependent?  Could you tell us how you might even begin?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment. Ok, is that mean we need to assume they are i.i.d to ease the estimation?

Comment: I don't see how one could even construct a valid estimate without having more information about *how* the data fail to be independent.